# Write out rows which have cell with specific value from large array in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, extract

I am reading in data from a large array (~50000 x 45). I am trying to extract rows from this which have their x_value (column 27) above a specific value (1.8 in this case).

I am able to write the array (p1) but each output row is the same, (the last row from the large array with x > 1.8)

Can anybody tell me how to write out this data properly?

Thanks

```
n = length(DAT);

bin = 1.8;

x_value = DAT(:,27); 

row = sum(x_value > bin);

for s = 1:n;

    if DAT(s,27) > bin

        for r = 1:row;

        p1(r,:) = DAT(s,:);

        end
    end
end
```

Comment: why are you summing? You can write `row = (x_value > bin);`. This is a logical indexing. Then you can extract as: `desiredValue`=x_value(row);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bin = 1.8;
column = 27;
rows = find(DAT(:,column) > bin);
p1 = DAT(rows,:);
```

Comment: You can also use logical indexing and omit `find`, _i.e_: `p1 = DAT(DAT(:,column) > bin, :);`